# 'float' object is not callable

Tags: python

Ошибка в 7 строке. Помогите исправить.

```
import math
from math import sqrt, exp, sin, log, cos, pi, asin

x = float(input())
y = float(input())

r1 = asin(cos(x + (sqrt(3) / 2 * pi())))  # <---
r2 = 1.2 + sqrt(2 - cos(y) ** 2)
r3 = x ** 2 + y ** 2 + 1
 
z = (r1 + r2) / r3
print(round(z, 5))
```

Comment: Строчка import math в этой программе не нужна.

Answer (score 1):

`pi` - это число, не надо его вызывать со скобками как функцию :)
Так работает:

```
r1 = asin(cos(x + (sqrt(3) / 2 * pi)))
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное